# How do I use isset properly here on my code?

Tags: php, sql

I'm having a website that only premium users can access and I have this code

```
<?php
    include_once('connectdb.php');
    $account = $_SESSION["username"];
    $sql = "SELECT acct_type FROM hash WHERE email = '$account'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            if ($row['acct_type'] == 'Paid'){
                echo"Not for free users";
                echo'<br>';
                exit();
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

How do I use `isset` here to block all free users and  only grant access to paid ones? 
PS: I cannot put `FREE` there because I have multiple types of accounts for my users.

I have already tried

```
if (!isset($row['acct_type'] == 'Paid'))
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: correct condition is  `(isset($row['acct_type']) &&  $row['acct_type']== 'Paid')`

Comment: `if ($row['acct_type'] == 'Paid'){
            echo"Not for free users";` isn't the error message contradicting? Also, the comparison needs to happen outside of the bracket for `(!isset($row['acct_type'] == 'Paid'))`, like `(!isset($row['acct_type']) || $row['acct_type'] != 'Paid')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `isset`, if `$result->num_rows > 0` then `$row['acct_type']` is guaranteed to be set. What you need to check is that the user has an account type which is `Paid`. You also need to exit if no rows were found (perhaps the user is not logged in and so `$_SESSION['username']` is not set):

```
include_once('connectdb.php');
$account = $_SESSION["username"];
$sql = "SELECT acct_type FROM hash WHERE email = '$account'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $paid = false;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $paid = $paid || ($row['acct_type'] == 'Paid');
    }
    if (!$paid) {
        echo "Not for free users";
        echo '<br>';
        exit();
    }
}
else {
    echo "Not logged in";
    echo '<br>';
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for others who will seek the same,

the isset is using to check if it exists and not empty.

```
 if(isset($variable) && $variable == 'other'){
    // do code
 }
```